# Python - How to find the point where the slope of contour changes?

Tags: python, opencv, contour

I have found the contour of the object through the function cv2.findContours and I want to know the coordinates where the contour changes slope relative to its front points, here I want that to be the starting point of the upper fin. . I would really appreciate it if you could give me a suitable suggestion. I hope you like this question

my input image : [input image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10hQY.png)

image after apply threshold with value 195 : [apply threshold](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HcZp2.png)

and i expect the result in like this : [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LxC1.png)

Comment: Get min and max locations of non-zero pixels along each column and get the difference (vertical height of white in your threshold) and plot that. Analyze the plot

Comment: I really don't quite understand your suggestion, it's good to have a specific example, thank you

Comment: See np.argmin and np.argmax to find the min and max Y values in each column. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71574600/find-the-minimum-plane-of-the-maximum-number-of-black-pixels-in-the-bottom-image/71576209#71576209 for an example

Comment: what you provided is very helpful for my problem, if you don't mind can you write me the specific command line for this problem, really thanks if you agree with my suggestion

Comment: Sorry, I cannot help at the moment. I am having computer problems with installing OpenCV

Comment: hope you will solve the problem with your computer easily, when you are done then please help support me

Comment: An alternate would be to get the vertical line intersection with the polygon of the boundary of your threshold shape (contour) for each vertical line in the image. You can use sympy for all that geometry. See https://docs.sympy.org/latest/index.html.  Once you have the top and bottom points for each column, you can find the difference and plot the difference vs column number, i.e. the X coordinate defining each column.

Comment: A simpler approach would be to use np.sum(thresh==255, axis=0) to get the sum of white pixels along each column. Then you can plot the sum for each column (i.e. x of the image from 0 to w).

Comment: I will do what you suggested, but I don't know how successful because I only understand a little of what you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try something like https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/auto_examples/edges/plot_skeleton.html - maybe the resultant graph could have features indicating the location of the fin

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to get the plot of vertical thickness using Numpy, Skimage and Mathplotlib in Python. (Not sure if that will help you)

- Read the image using Skimage (or OpenCV or PIL)
- Convert to grayscale using Skimage
- Crop the image to remove a band of white at the top and right sides using Numpy
- Get a count of all non-zero pixels along each column using Numpy
- Make a plot of count vs x axis using Mathplotlib
- Save the plot
- Compute slope
- Make a plot of slope vs x axis using Mathplotlib
- Save the plot

Input Cropped:

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage import io as io
from skimage.color import rgb2gray

# Read source image.
img = io.imread('fish_binary.png')
h,w = img.shape[:2]

# convert to gray
gray = rgb2gray(img)

# crop image to remove white at top and right
gray = gray[3:h, 0:w-3]

# get sum of white pixels along each column
count = np.sum(gray!=0, axis=0)

print(count)

# plot count

# x axis values
x = np.arange(0,w-3)

# corresponding y axis values
y = count
  
# plotting the points 
plt.plot(x, y)
  
# naming the x axis
plt.xlabel('x - axis')

# naming the y axis
plt.ylabel('y - axis: count')
  
# giving a title to my graph
plt.title('Graph of Count vs X')

# save figure
plt.savefig('fish_binary_plot_sum.png')

# function to show the plot
plt.show()


# compute derivative (slope = DY/DX = count difference between points DX=1)

# put x and y (count) into lists
xList = []
yList = []
for i, cnt in enumerate(count):
    xList.append(i)
    yList.append(cnt)
        
# compute slope and put into list
slopeList = []
for j in range(0, w-3):
    x1 = xList[j]
    y1 = yList[j]
    if j == w-4:
        j = j-1
    x2 = xList[j+1]
    y2 = yList[j+1]
    Dx = x2 - x1
    Dy = y2 - y1
    if Dx == 0:
        slope = 0
    else:
        slope = Dy/Dx
    slopeList.append(slope)



# plot slope

# x axis values
x = xList

# corresponding y axis values
y = slopeList
  
# plotting the points 
plt.plot(x, y)
  
# naming the x axis
plt.xlabel('x - axis')

# naming the y axis
plt.ylabel('y - axis: slope')
  
# giving a title to my graph
plt.title('Graph of Slope vs X')

# save figure
plt.savefig('fish_binary_plot_slope.png')

# function to show the plot
plt.show()
```

Resulting Plot of Sums:

[image]

Resulting Plot of Slopes:

[image]

You may want to smooth the slopes and plot them skipping x values.